# Loses the connection name when obtaining a record (Outside Laravel / enssegers/laravel-mongodb)

Tags: eloquent, jenssegers-mongodb

I need your help, I am using Eloquent and enssegers / laravel-mongodb outside Laravel Framework, I have managed to correctly configure both Eloquent and laravel-mongodb and it works correctly to insert and obtain results, however, when trying to modify a registry, eloquent loses the connection name by throwing the following error:

```
Argument 1 passed to Jenssegers\Mongodb\Query\Builder::__construct() must be an instance of Jenssegers\Mongodb\Connection, instance of Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection given, called in /www/html/syberianbox/sachiel/vendor/jenssegers/mongodb/src/Jenssegers/Mongodb/Eloquent/Model.php on line 421
```

I share the configuration of Eloquent through Capsula and laravel-mongodb

```
$this->_capsule = new Capsule();

$this->_capsule->getDatabaseManager()->extend('mongodb', function($config) {
    return new MongodbConnect($config);
});

//MySQL connection, $ this -> _ config contains an array with the correct values
$this->addConnection('default', [
    'driver'     => $this->_config['default']['driver']
    ,'host'      => $this->_config['default']['host']
    ,'database'  => $this->_config['default']['database']
    ,'username'  => $this->_config['default']['username']
    ,'password'  => $this->_config['default']['password']
    ,'charset'   => $this->_config['default']['charset']
    ,'collation' => $this->_config['default']['collation']
    ,'prefix'    => $this->_config['default']['prefix']
]);

//MongoDB connection
$this->addConnection('archivos', [
    'driver'     => $this->_config['archivos']['driver']
    ,'host'      => $this->_config['archivos']['host']
    ,'port'      => $this->_config['archivos']['port']
    ,'database'  => $this->_config['archivos']['database']
]);
```

Model:

```
<?php
namespace Instances\Generic\Models\CFDI;

use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model;

class Archivo extends Model
{
    protected $collection = 'cfdi';
    protected $connection = 'archivos';
}
```

Execute model:

```
$archivoDB = Archvio::Where('_id',$id)->first();
$this->_logger->info('Archivo: ', $archivoDB);
$archivoDB->uuid = $uuid;
$archivoDB->type = $type;
$archivoDB->content = $content;

$archivoDB->save();
```

Logger:

```
[2019-02-12 14:20:36:511603][Instances/Generic/Modules/Administracion/ArchivosController.php : 75][Info][30117] Archivo: 
Instances\Generic\Models\CFDI\Archivo Object
(
    [collection:protected] => cfdi
    [connection:protected] => 
    [primaryKey:protected] => _id
    [keyType:protected] => string
    .....
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem, however it is more a patch than a complete solution.

I extend the class Model of jenssegers / laravel-mongodb and on I write the method getConnectionName () and return the name of the expected connection, as in my case it is only a single connection the name remains as static, however, the method gives the arrow to be able to include all the necessary logic to identify the connection with the model in question

Model:

```
<?php
namespace Syberianbox\Db;

use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model;


class Monomodel extends Model
{
    public function getConnectionName() {
        return 'archivos';
    }
}
```